# Array only prints length instead of contents

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

My array is printing out the length instead of its contents. I genuinely looked for an answer but found none. Here is my code:

```
<p id="para">

</p>

var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];

myArray = myArray.unshift('Charlie');

document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = myArray;
```

I want this array to print out Charlie,1,2,3,4,5 but instead it prints out 6. What dumb thing am I doing wrong here?

Comment: "The unshift() method adds one or more elements to the beginning of an array **and returns the new length of the new array.**" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift

Comment: Just use myArray.unshift('Charlie');

Comment: Is there a way I can achieve Charlie,1,2,3,4,5?

Comment: You've already achieved it, the array is modified "in place".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading [the docs for Array.unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) is says that it *returns the length* of the array.

> The unshift() method adds one or more elements to the beginning of an
>   array and returns the new length of the new array.

You might just want to remove the assign operator like so

```js
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

myArray.unshift('Charlie');

document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = myArray.join(',');
```

```html
<div id="para">

</div>
```

Comment: What is the logic behind myArray = myArray.unshift('Charlie') returning 6?

Comment: @Brixsta All I can say is that this is the way it works as per the standard. It's specified in the docs I linked above. The unshift method returns the new length.

Comment: @Brixsta Before the unshift the length is *5* but then after the unshift the length is *6*, which is returned.

Answer (score 1):

.unshift returns the length of the array. So what you had done in the above code equated myArray to myArray.unshift()'s return value. myArrays value became the length of the array which was 6

So all you have to code is

```
myArray.unshift('Charlie');
```

```js
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];
//console.log(myArray);
myArray.unshift('Charlie');
document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = myArray;
```

```html
<p id="para"></p>
```

A nicer way of presenting this would be

```js
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];
//console.log(myArray);
myArray.unshift('Charlie');
var str='';
for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++)
{
str=str+myArray[i]+" ";
}
document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<p id="para">

</p>
```

Comment: For the second example you could do `myArray.join(' ')` instead of the loop